# rewards the products qualify for

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
products purchased
--------------------------
bana
bana
bana
stra
kiwi

reward requirements table (related to a rewards table)
reward id, products
----------------------
1,bana
1,bana
1,bana
2,stra
2,bana
3,stra
4,cart
5,bana
5,bana
5,oliv
```

Can you help me with sql to get rewards
the products purchased qualifies for?

In the case above the reward ids would be:

```
1
2
3
```

If there is a better design that would make the solution easier I welcome those as well. I'm using product names for the sake of easier explaining, I hope. (I'll replace with product ids later)

Comment: Could you explain what the reward requirements table means?  Do you get 5 only if you purchase 2 `bana`s and 1 `oliv`?  Is 2 rewarded for either a `stra` or `bana`?  Are there really comma delimited lists in the `products` column?

Comment: It's an AND condition. You have to have all to qualify. For reward 2 you have to have both. For reward id 1 you need 3 bana to fulfill requirement.

Comment: No comma delimited, sorry my mistake.

Comment: If I put a requirement of 4 bananas the sqlfiddle query will still pick up the reward 1, which would not be correct behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will solve your problem.

```
select r.reward_id
from (
  select reward_id, product, count(*) needed
  from reward_requirements
  group by reward_id, product
) r
left join (
  select product, count(*) bought
  from products_purchased
  group by product 
) p on r.product=p.product and p.bought >= r.needed
group by r.reward_id
having count(reward_id) = count(distinct p.product)
order by r.reward_id
```

To make your design better, you could redo the reward_requirements to have the columns (product, needed) instead of having to list it multiple times.  It will also get rid of the first subquery.

Answer (score 2):

With this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE            product
(
    product_id          int IDENTITY
    , name              varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE            requirement
(
    requirement_id      int IDENTITY
    , product_id        int
    , quantity          int
    , reward_id         int
)

CREATE TABLE            reward
(
    reward_id           int IDENTITY
    , reward            varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE            purchased
(
    purchased_id        int IDENTITY
    , product_id        int
    , quantity          int
)
```

Your query becomes:

```
SELECT      requirement.reward_id
FROM        requirement
            LEFT JOIN purchased
                ON  purchased.product_id = requirement.product_id
                AND purchased.quantity >= requirement.quantity
GROUP BY    requirement.reward_id
HAVING      COUNT(purchased.product_id) = COUNT(requirement.reward_id);
```

Here's a SQLFiddle to play around with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e93c9/7